# Feasible level for Yuffie to be at in order to attempt Godo's pagoda

Tags: final-fantasy-7

What is the best (lower than lvl50) level to have Yuffie at in order to **attempt** fighting her way through the 5 bosses of Godo's pagoda in Wutai with some chance for success?

Comment: Well, the *best* level would be 99. You might rephrase this as "what level do I need to get Yuffie up to in order to have a reasonable shot at beating Godo's pagoda?"

Comment: @ObliviousSage I thought with words such as optimal and attempt, the "level 99 with master materias" answer wouldn't be a problem. I'll reformat the question a bit tho, thanks.

Comment: reasonable depends on materials too, if you have a KOTR materia you can do it as long as she has the MP to summon it.

Comment: Each boss has a specific weakness if I remember correctly. If you can exploit them properly then you shouldn't have too much trouble.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

General hints for success:

1. *Counter* materia is your friend. The higher level it is, the better your chance at countering attacks. *Barrier* materia is also incredibly helpful.
2. *Restore* materia should be able to cast *Cure 2* at least.
3. As a general rule of thumb, *Restore*, *Barrier*, *Counter*, and *Time* materia should always be equipped in Yuffie's materia slots.
4. If you can do it, *Haste* followed by *Barrier* should be the first two spells you cast on Yuffie each fight.
5. You're allowed to re-equip Yuffie between each fight. Use this time to your advantage to prepare Yuffie for the next level boss and heal any HP loss or adverse status effects.
6. If you lose a fight, the game does not end, so don't feel afraid to try out beating the bosses.
7. Once you beat a boss, you don't have to battle them again when re-climbing the pagoda.

## Level 1 Boss - [Gorki](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Gorkii)

### Statistics

```
Level - 30       | HP - 3,000     | MP - 150
Attack - 71      | Magic - 75     | Defense - 60
M. Defense - 280 | Dexterity - 70 | Evade - 25
EXP - 1,500      | AP - 50        | Gil - 0
```

Gorki casts [Demi2](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Graviga), so equipping Yuffie's armor with a *Gravity-Elemental* materia combination will most likely nullify this attack. Equipping *Counter* materia as well as at least a level 2 *Restore* materia will help keep the battle going in your favor.

## Level 2 Boss - [Shake](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Shake)

### Statistics

```
Level - 32       | HP - 4,000     | MP - 180
Attack - 71      | Magic - 75     | Defense - 60
M. Defense - 280 | Dexterity - 68 | Evade - 1
EXP - 2,2000     | AP - 50        | Gil - 0
```

Shake's main attack is the *Rage Bomber* attack, which does a fair amount of damage to Yuffie. Once again, equipping *Counter* as well as a level 2 or higher *Restore* materia will help keep the battle going in your favor.

## Level 3 Boss - [Chekhov](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Chekhov)

### Statistics

```
Level - 34       | HP - 5,000     | MP - 210
Attack - 71      | Magic - 75     | Defense - 60
M. Defense - 280 | Dexterity - 70 | Evade - 1
EXP - 2,900      | AP - 50        | Gil - 0
```

Chekhov's *Stare Down* attack will cause the Stop effect. To guard against this, equip the *Jem Ring* accessory before the fight, as this will nullify Stop. She has no other large attacks, so keep the *Counter* and *Restore* materia equipped and keep Yuffie's health up during the fight.

## Level 4 Boss - [Staniv](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Staniv)

### Statistics

```
Level - 36       | HP - 6,000     | MP - 240
Attack - 71      | Magic - 75     | Defense - 60
M. Defense - 280 | Dexterity - 72 | Evade - 1
EXP - 3,600      | AP - 50        | Gil - 0
```

Staniv is a physical brawler, and can inflict Sadness with his *War Cry* ability. Once again, keep *Counter* and *Restore* materia equipped and Yuffie's HP up during the battle.

## Final Boss - [Godo](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Godo_(Boss))

### Statistics

```
Level - 41       | HP - 10,000    | MP - 1,000
Attack - 70      | Magic - 45     | Defense - 60
M. Defense - 100 | Dexterity - 68 | Evade - 1
EXP - 5,000      | AP - 60        | Gil - 40,000
```

Strategy from the Final Fantasy Wikia:

> It is recommended Godo is **poisoned** at the start of the battle. Yuffie should equip an **Enemy Skill** Materia if it needs to learn **Trine**, as Godo is one of the only three sources where Trine can be learned. Godo is not immune to Gravity, so **Demi** spells can do several thousand damage to him. The **Trine** skill can also used to do heavy damage. If the **Gravity Materia is linked to an HP Absorb Materia**, Yuffie can heal herself while draining Godo's health with Demi.
>   The best way for the player to finish him off is leave him poisoned, sit in the back row defending with the Counter Attack Materia equipped and Big Guard on. Godo has no chance to heal, and the battle will end.
>
> An alternative way to prevent him curing is for the player to cast **Reflect** on him, or use a Mirror item.
>
> Many of Godo's attacks, particularly Bio2 and Demi3, cost a lot of MP to cast. *Thus, if the player can endure his attacks until he runs out of MP, Godo is virtually helpless*. Magic Hammer can also be used to drain Godo out of MP. Once he has no MP left, he will be limited to the Beast Sword attack, which is weak and easily healed.

Comment: Boss stats and Godo strategy came from the [Final Fantasy Wikia](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Final_Fantasy_Wiki) while the other boss strategies and general hints came from my own head after playing through the battles a couple times.